# How to Login to Stack Overflow in Chrome with a different Google ID than the one I'm using for Chrome

Tags: discussion, login, google-chrome

Say I have a Stack Overflow account using personal@gmail.com for login. However, on another computer, I have logged into Chrome using work@gmail.com. When I try to login to Stack Overlow on this computer, it detects Chrome login and asks me to Create a Stack Overflow ID with work@gmail.com. I don't even get an option to Login with another Google ID.

Is there a workaround where I could be logged into Chrome with work@gmail.com and be able to login to Stack Overflow using the account I made with personal@gmail.com

Relevance/Context: I have a Stack Overflow account with my personal Google ID. However, I have logged into Chrome at work with a different Google ID. I want to stay logged in into Chrome with work ID and use my Stack Overflow account with personal ID.

Comment: Why would this be migrated from MSE?  It doesn't seem to be specific to SO.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Note: Since this answer was posted, changes to Stack Exchange have made the ability to use one browser with multiple accounts impossible. If you don't want to logout and log back in again, you'll need to use multiple browsers or, for those browsers that support it, multiple user profiles.

---

I use one Google account for Stack Overflow and related sites, and a different Google account for things like Science Fiction & Fantasy and Movies. I can move between each site or have sites open in multiple tabs and Stack Exchange uses the correct account for each.

You simply need to use Google's multiple login feature to be signed in to both your personal and work accounts.

Click your profile picture in the upper right on any Google site. (Gmail, for instance.) Click "Add Account". Choose the other account and sign in with those credentials.

Now, for those Google apps that support it, you can switch between the accounts (or, for some, have one account open in each tab for the same app.)

You might need to log out of the Stack Exchange site you want to change. Then when you go to log in and use your Google credentials, as long as you're logged in to both Google accounts you should be presented with a page (from Google) that lets you choose which account you want to use for the Open ID sign in.

Comment: You may need to update your answer

Answer (score 15):

You can do that by following these simple steps:

1. Logout of your workID on Gmail
2. Login to your personal ID on Gmail
3. Login to Stack Overflow (will automatically be logged in from your personal ID)
4. Logout of Gmail (your personal ID)
5. Login to Gmail using your work ID

Comment: This is how I've managed as well.

Comment: Inelegant, but worked. Thanks!

Comment: This is horrible UX. I can't log out of my work account at all, and I can't get Stack Exchange to let me log in with my personal google account from my work computer (not sure why, probably related to automatic redirects my company uses). I think my only options are to a) create a new password for Stack Exchange and tie that account to my work email (and hope that I can switch it back if that email ever goes away), or b) create a totally separate account to use from work and start over from scratch?

Comment: I'm so mad this worked *cries-laugh*. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

I too was initially troubled by this. But trust me, *this is not a bug, but feature*.
On clicking sign in with Google, it simply checks how many google accounts you are already signed in to. If it is one, it logs you in with that, otherwise gives you a choice in case they are more than one.

So, all you have to do is ***Add Account*** at Google.com, and reattempt login at Stack Exchange.

Comment: Nope, does not work.   On my iphone i added my alternate Google account , then logged into that as chrome, then when i open the iphone stackoverflow app to login, it doesnt work.  it still thinks im on my main account.   sad.

Comment: Worked for me - very simple, but I hadn't thought of it, so thanks!

Answer (score -4):

The google logon works for every tab in your browser. You can't use 2 simultanously with the exception of:

- using a different browser (e.g. Firefox,Safari)
- using [personalized copies](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/2364824?hl=en) of Chrome
- starting new chrome window/tab in private mode

Comment: This isn't true. I use two separate Google logins for Stack Exchange sites. I can have one site open in one tab with one account, and a different site open in a different tab in the same browser instance with a different Google account. I don't need to use incognito mode.

Comment: You clearly have a good reputation and I mean no offence by this, but I would suggest removing this answer as there is an answer that better addresses the OP's question and presents a simpler solution

Answer (score -8):

The workaround is to open up a second browser (Firefox or Safari)

Comment: You clearly have a good reputation and I mean no offence by this, but I would suggest removing this answer as there is an answer that better addresses the OP's question and presents a simpler solution