# Log in to Stack Overflow with a login name not Google ID

Tags: discussion, login, google, firefox

I have long had a Stack Overflow account using an email (from work) + password login.

Inadvertently, from home I recently created a login against my personal Google/Gmail ID, from within Firefox (*not* Chrome), where I sit logged into Gmail all the time. From Firefox there I can now only login to Stack Overflow using my Google account. At present I have to remember to start up an "anonymous" Firefox to prevent this and be able to do the email login.

1. Is this the only and simplest procedure I can use? Isn't there any way to force an Stack Overflow email login now from my situation?
2. Alternatively or instead, it occurs to me that two accounts mean my reputation points are separate, and it's all a hassle. Am I allowed now to "combine" these two accounts into one (and retain my reputation points) in either direction?

(Please excuse me if this question has been asked before. Maybe [How to Login to Stack Overflow in Chrome with a different Google ID than the one I'm using for Chrome](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251166/how-to-login-to-stack-overflow-in-chrome-with-a-different-google-id-than-the-one) answers this sufficiently for my case, I can't get my head around it. But I'm looking for a response on *two* possible solutions.)

Comment: What are you trying to actually accomplish?  Do you want to have a single account with being able to login via your work email as you did before and your new Google login?  Or do you just want to login the old way with your work email?

Comment: As I wrote, I would actually like a choice of either/both.  I would then probably start out with being able to login "separately" for a while (case #1), and then consider whether I would actually like to merge the two accounts (case #2).  Hence the two solutions sought :)  The final situation will depend on how easy/hard each of these proves to be.

Comment: Without explicitly logging out each time from Stack Exchange, there is no way to use the browser with 2 different accounts unless you do you have been doing (opening it in "private" or "incognito" mode).  But you can use separate browsers to accomplish it.  Have Firefox logged in with your work credentials and Chome logged in with your Google credentials.

Comment: Just one word of caution though.... while it is not forbidden to have separate accounts, you need to be very careful you aren't using the separate accounts to do things you normally couldn't do with 1 account, such as evading posting limits, or voting limits, or voting on your own posts.  I'd even be careful editing your own posts with the other account as well.  Basically if you keep them from ever crossing paths, you won't have any problems, but if you start to interact with your own posts, you could find yourself suspended

Comment: Thank you for your observations.  I only use one browser, Firefox, so no "separate browsers" possible, will have to stick to one being "Private".  It is possible I will unintentionally mix up and access a post from the other account.  **SO**: What about #2?  Can I "merge" accounts while retaining Reputation?  Can I change a long-standing "email name + password" account over to using Google ID now?  Is the fact that I have already created the Google ID account (with small Reputation) going to be an impediment to merging in the other account? Should I start a new question for this?!

Comment: Merging accounts can be done.  You just need to contact the Stack Exchange community team to do so.  Just go to http://stackoverflow.com/contact and select "I need to merge user profiles" and fill out the rest.  They will contact you back with further instructions

Comment: Many thanks.  If you wish to summarise your comments into an Answer I would Accept it (up to you).

Comment: I have just seen http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/290774/489865, which explains I can have multiple logins against one account.  This would be my ideal solution.  Except that because I have already created the Google ID as an SO user I assume I cannot do that without getting this second account removed first?

Comment: when you merge the accounts, both logins should be retained, so it will accomplish the same thing

Answer (score 1):

With Firefox, you can start multiple sessions at the same time, when you use separate profiles. See [Command Line Options](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Command_Line_Options#-new-instance) for details.

On the command line, start Firefox with

```
firefox --new-instance --ProfileManager
```

Create a new profile, e.g. "SO-1", start Firefox and login with your first account. Start Firefox again in a separate command line and create another Profile, "SO-2", and then login with your second account.

Of course, you must pay attention, which Firefox window you use when asking or answering questions. Best use different profile images for the two accounts.

Comment: Thank you for pointing this out.  In my case though by the time I have remembered to set up separate profiles and paid attention to which one I am launching, I may just as well use my existing "anonymous" method via `-private` command line argument.